# Is there a way to use ngx-ui tooltip with ngFor in angular2/4? (angular2 tooltip libraries appear to all have problems, need expert help)

Tags: angular

I want to use a tooltip here:
https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-ui

I have a list of objects:
mylist = [{'name':'Apple'},{'name':'Banana'}, {'name':'Pineapple'}]

When I do the following, it looks good:

```
<a [tooltipPlacement]="'top'" [tooltipType]="'tooltip'" ngx-tooltip [tooltipType]="'popover'" [tooltipPlacement]="'top'" [tooltipTemplate]="popoverTemplate" (mouseover)="tooltipModel.text = 'Apple'">Apple</a>
```

Problem is when I try to ngFor it like this:

```
<a *ngFor="let fruit of mylist;" [tooltipPlacement]="'top'" [tooltipType]="'tooltip'" ngx-tooltip [tooltipType]="'popover'" [tooltipPlacement]="'top'" [tooltipTemplate]="popoverTemplate" (mouseover)="tooltipModel.text = 'Apple'">{{fruit.name}}</a>
```

Event though I am hardcoding the tooltip text, the tooltip does not show. Is there a way around this or is the library broken and does not support ngFor?

All I want to do is have a tooltip, I tried other packages like angular2-tooltips, which does not work well when you have a nested container. ngx-tooltip attaches tooltips to the body element of the HTML, which makes sure the tooltip is always displayed on top. Am disheartened by the fact there appears to be no easy way to get a good tooltip working. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved using [ngx-tooltip](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip#tooltip-directive),

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <a [tooltip] = "item.toolTipMessage"  placement="left">
       {{item.name}}
   </a>
```

Comment: I tried using ngx-tooltip within a tab-component with angular material (https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) and from within the tab container, the tooltip gets cutoff/hidden... I know Angular2 Material has tooltips too, but I want to be able to use html templates inside my tooltips.

Comment: depending on your implementation. create a plunker to reproduce i will fix it for you

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/DhrkpRo8WqmH18b7tWk3?p=preview I do not want to use ViewEncapsulation.None to get around this.

Comment: yes. its because your component is in the edge and you are having another component overlapped. use the right tooltip option or give some padding value

Comment: This is the problem, if my button/text I want to hover is at the very top left corner of the screen... then part of it will still be cut off. I want the tooltip to overlap the entire page. If you try using ngx-ui tooltip, it doesn't matter if its located on edge or not, the tooltip will always show above everything else. I am surprised out of all the angular2 libraries, ngx-ui is the only one that has a tooltip that behaves this way... (unless you happen to know of a workaround or alternate library)

Comment: this will also work but you are having `margin value` it calculates value dynamically based on the srcElement position so you are facing the hiding issue

Comment: Can you show a plunkr with some way to avoid this hiding issue? It would be a miracle... am surprised Angular2 tooltip ecosystem has issues like this.

Comment: which plunker? I didnt get you

Comment: I mean, are you able to show how to get around the hiding issue and show how to solve it through a plunkr? Or is the library I am using and ngx-tooltip just broken by design?